# Starting Instagram application via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram

Good day, everyone. I've recently got the annoying problem - when i try to start Instagram app through Intent, the Instagram activity starts for a moment, and closes immediately, returning me back to my app. This problem appeared only one or two days ago, and the same code worked before as expected. Does anyone met the same behavior? Maybe some workarounds exist?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("image/jpeg");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+savedPhotoPath));// //savedPhotoPath is the path of my picture stored somewhere in the sdcard
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: tried, Instagram application appears in the list of available apps, and when i choose it - the same flow goes (open for a second and back to previous app)

Comment: have you tried my code or yours?...because the putExtra makes all the difference..

Comment: Try to avoid calling an actually existing app with an implicit intent. It's use is rather worrying, speaking from an security angle of view. (Besides he is asking for "Starting" not "Sharing" the image)

Comment: For design purpose i shouldn't give a user chance to choose most suitable app, since he already pressed "Share to Instagram" button. But the solution @dvs offered, combining with extra setting in my intent (intent.setPackage("com.instagram.android")), resulted in opening the Instagram application without choosing dialog.